# Oracle Inner Classes Example

Tags: java, inner-classes

I don't understand this line:

```
interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { }
```

since there is no difference between DataStructeIterator and iterator can't we just remove this line and instead say:

```
private class EvenIterator implements java.util.iterator<Integer> { //code goes here}
```

What am I missing?

```
public class DataStructure {

    // Create an array
    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        // fill the array with ascending integer values
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void printEven() {

        // Print out values of even indices of the array
        DataStructureIterator iterator = this.new EvenIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { } 

    // Inner class implements the DataStructureIterator interface,
    // which extends the Iterator<Integer> interface

    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {

        // Start stepping through the array from the beginning
        private int nextIndex = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {

            // Check if the current element is the last in the array
            return (nextIndex <= SIZE - 1);
        }        

        public Integer next() {

            // Record a value of an even index of the array
            Integer retValue = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInts[nextIndex]);

            // Get the next even element
            nextIndex += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        // Fill the array with integer values and print out only
        // values of even indices
        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();
        ds.printEven();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is from Oracle tutorial? Seriously. Who writes `nextIndex <= SIZE - 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right; for most purposes you can do away with the `DataStructureIterator` and use `Iterator<Integer>` directly.

Defining `DataStructureIterator` like this creates a shorthand notation for `Iterator<Integer>`, but it's a *very poor* shorthand. It's not at all like, for example, a typedef in C.

You can assign any object that implements `DataStructureIterator` to `Iterator<Integer>`, but you cannot assign all objects that implement `Iterator<Integer>` to `DataStructureIterator`.

So, although it's legal to define an empty interface like that, there is not much point to it. And it can lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things out. And for the second part I think that I've guessed why we can't assign an Object from Iterator<Integer> to DataStructureIterator and that is because the compiler doesn't know if the DataStructureIterator interface is the same as the Iterator<Integer>